# Is it possible to access the actualStartTime value on another users livebroadcast using Youtube v3 api?

Tags: youtube-api, youtube-data-api

I am trying to access the snippet.actualStartTime value of a youtube livebroadcast, using the v3 API.

I have obtained an oauth2 token, and I am able to retrieve this data just fine, but only for my own channel.

I can't see anything on the documentation (https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/live/docs/liveBroadcasts)
that indicates this information is private/restricted, it even has a specific flag for "mine", indicating that it is indeed possible to fetch it for other channels, but no matter what i try, i can't seem to gain access to it when providing a videoId from another channel.

Even if i try to query for only the "status" of the livebroadcast it returns an empty items[] array.

This is the request I'm using:

```
Axios.get(`https://youtube.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/liveBroadcasts?id=${videoId}&part=status`,
            {
                headers: {
                    Authorization: `Bearer ${token}`,
                    Accept: 'application/json'
                }
            })
```

Answer (score 0):

[YouTube Data API v3](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3) [Videos: list](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/videos/list) endpoint with [`part=liveStreamingDetails`](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/videos/list#part) returns [`item/snippet/liveStreamingDetails/actualStartTime`](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/videos#liveStreamingDetails.actualStartTime) correctly for any YouTube channel.